# Obtaining value from an array

Tags: python

I tried a lot of method to allow me to get the value from signalxIP but it doesn't seem to work.. Value from appliedFieldIP and signalxIP is uneven

```
appliedFieldIP = [10,5,0,-5,-10,-5,0,5,10]
signalxIP = [2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

The range i want is from 0 to -5 to -10. I used the code below to achieve it. But i am unable to get the value from signalxIP.

```
aIP = appliedFieldIP[:appliedFieldIP.index(min(appliedFieldIP)) + 1] # 10,5,0,-5,-10
x2 = (filter(lambda x: x <= 0 <= max(aIP), aIP)) # 0,-5,-10
print aIP >>> 10,5,0,-5,-10
print x2 >>> 0,-5,-10
```

For example

```
if x2 is 0, y2 that is from signalxIP must be 0.
   x2 is -5, y2 is -1
   x2 is -10, y2 is -2
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac its at the example. 
y2 = [ 0, -1, -2 ]

Comment: I'm afraid that does not explain much :(

Comment: The code / examples you have supplied are not enough. In order for us to help you we must have more information. It would be great if you could copy all relevant code here, and show us what the input/output that you are getting is (or any errors) and then also provide what you want the expected output to be.

Comment: `x <= 0 <= max(aIP)` - I don't think that comparison makes sense. `x` isn't even involved in `0 <= max(aIP)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really ugly, but:

```
appliedFieldIP = [10,5,0,-5,-10,-5,0,5,10]
signalxIP = [2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2]

zipped = list(zip(appliedFieldIP, signalxIP))
cutoff_index = appliedFieldIP.index(min(appliedFieldIP))+1
zipped2 = zipped[:cutoff_index]
# this aIP should be the same as aIP in your code
aIP = [pair[0] for pair in zipped2]
intermediate = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] <= 0 <= max(aIP), zipped2))
x2 = [pair[0] for pair in intermediate]
y2 = [pair[1] for pair in intermediate]

print(aIP)
print(x2)
print(y2)
```

Result:

```
[10, 5, 0, -5, -10]
[0, -5, -10]
[0, -1, -2]
```

Basically, the idea is that you `zip` `appliedFieldIP` and `signalxIP` together (giving you `zipped`), and then perform operations on the zipped lists, so that whenever you cut elements out of the `appliedFieldIP` part, you simultaneously cut the same elements out of the `signalxIP` part. At the end, we extract only the `signalxIP` part, giving us the list `y2`. You could shorten this a fair bit, but I left it somewhat verbose because I wasn't sure which parts of this (e.g. `aIP`) you might need to reuse later.